# How to check if a 2D point is inside or outside a 2D Closed Bezier Curve using Python?

Tags: python, math, bezier, curve, points

[image]

Hello,

in my 2d software i have two inputs available:

an array of XY points

```
[(x,y),(1,1),(2,2),(2,3),(-1,3),...]
```

and another matrix representing the closed 2D bezier curve handles

```
[((x,y),(x,y),(x,y)),
 ((-1,-1),(1,1),(1,2)),
 ((1,1),(2,2),(2,3)),
 ...]
```

How can i check if a point is inside or outside the given curve using python ? using preferably numpy maybe

Comment: No i just have some bezier handle available as input

Comment: yep, my apologize, I just missed the second matrix. It is possible, but first i have to read how to define the curve as parametric equation

Comment: Maybe you can provide sample (but complete) input data, a few "testing points" and expected result? It would make others (me at least) more willing to try to help and more confident while presenting the answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how the theory of Bezier curves, so if your second list of points is a kind of compressed way to represent a Bezier curve, first try to sample some points of the curve with the precision you want.
So you have n points of your curve, and then you can apply a simple PIP algorithm : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon

I can explain in details later if you want to know how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I cant write code right here, because I need the entire program to understand properly, however I may provide two approaches how to do that.

1. The hardest way is to approximate each Bézier curve by a polyline. And then, according to the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_in_polygon) you can use two techniques:

- **Ray casting algorithm:** the shorthand of the algorithm: You put a ray, which starting from a point and goes through the entire polygon to an another point. Some lines lies inside a polygon, some outside. And then you check to which line belongs a specific point Looks like this:

[image]

- **Winding number algorithm:** [A little bit about winding numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winding_number). So if a winding number is non-zero, the point lies inside the polygon

The huge drawback of this approach is that the accuracy depends on how close you approximated a curve to a polyline.

2. The second way is to use a bitmap. For example, you set your points to the white then render the area under the curve to the black and see if your points remain white. This method is more accurate and the fastest one, because you can use the GPU for the render.

And some links related to the first a approach:

1. https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#intersections
2. http://web.mit.edu/hyperbook/Patrikalakis-Maekawa-Cho/node80.html

Comment: I just realised that at some point in the past, there actually _was_ a dedicated section on determining point-in-shape and apparently some time over the last 7 years it disappeared. I'm currently completely redoing the tech stack for the Primer so I guess I'll have to reintroduce that section.